# Find the image of upper half plane under $ w= \log (1-z^2)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of upper half plane under $ w= \log (1-z^2)$

I start by assuming that $ w$ is compostion of two function $w_1 = \log z$ and $ w_2 = 1-z^2 $
But I get stuck with this guess.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Start with finding the image of the upper half-plane under the map $z \mapsto 1-z^2$. Then apply what you know about the logarithm to find the image of that set under $\log$.

Comment: Does the "upper half plane" include the real numbers? If so, $1-z^2$ roams over all complex numbers, If not, it excludes the ray along the real number line from $1$ to minus infinity.

Comment: @RoryDaulton $ Im z>0 $

Comment: Is that $\log$ the principal value or any value of the logarithm? (If the principal value, it is usually written $\operatorname{Log}$.) If the principal value, do you take the argument as in $(-\pi,\pi]$ as is most common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous, though your comment helps. But let's assume that the limitation on $z$ is $\operatorname{Im}(z)>0$ and the logarithm is the principal value such that $-\pi<\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{Log}(u))\le\pi$ for any complex number $u$.

We are given $\operatorname{Im}(z)>0$. This means that $0<\operatorname{Arg}(z)<\pi$.

Then $0<\operatorname{Arg}(z^2)<2\pi$ (where the argument is generalized) and $z^2\ne 0$. This means $z^2$ roams over the entire complex plane except for the non-negative real numbers.

Then $1-z^2$ roams over the entire complex plane except for the real numbers $x$ such that $x\le 1$, i.e. except for the ray that starts at $1$ and goes to minus infinity. Note that this excludes the negative real numbers, zero, and the real interval $(0,1]$.

The image of the principal logarithm function $\operatorname{Log}(u)$, where $u=x+yi$ covers all complex numbers, is $-\pi<y\le \pi$; i.e. the horizontal strip between $y=-\pi$ and $y=\pi$, including the upper line but not the lower one.

[image: Image of Log(u) for all complex u]

However, we must remove part of that range for your function $\operatorname{Log}(1-z^2)$. Removing zero from the domain changes nothing, since the logarithm is undefined. Removing the negative reals from the domain means removing the argument of pi from the domain, meaning we remove $y=\pi$ from the range. Thus we remove the upper line of the horizontal strip, showing that by changing the solid line in our graph to a dashed line.

Lastly we remove the reals in $(0,1]$ from the domain, which means removing the argument zero and the modulus between zero and 1. Thus we remove the ray with $y=0$ and $x\le 0$: the ray on the real number line from zero to minus infinity. We show that by placing a dashed line there:

[image: Range of Log(1-z^2) for z in the upper half plane]

An analytic description of the range in terms of $x$ and $y$ is

$$\text{$(-\pi<y<\pi)$ and not $(y=0$ and $x\le 0)$}$$